# Drawable folder structure in monodroid?

Tags: android, xamarin.android

In android there is a structure of

```
rez
  - Drawable-hdpi
  - Drawable-ldpi
  - Drawable-mdpi
```

in monodroid I just see

```
Resources
    -Drawable
```

Do I delete this folder and make the above 3 folders?

Answer (score 1):

Yep, all the same Android resource folder rules apply.